# Combine first column from multiple files

Tags: python, file, file-io, dictionary

I have file#1 which I provide at standard input:

```
{123:{'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 0, 'sscore !=0': 15}}
{456:{'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 1, 'sscore !=0': 19}}
{789:{'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 1, 'sscore !=0': 20}}
```

I have file #2:

```
{'+1': {'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 0, 'sscore !=0': 15}}
{'0': {'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 1, 'sscore !=0': 19}}
{'0': {'all_uppercase': 0, '#': 0, 'sscore !=0': 8}}
```

My output should be as-is:

```
 123 15 +1
 456 19 0
 789 20 0
```

There is significance why these lines have to be in order. So it means for id- 123,456,789 the binaries are +1,0,0 and values 15,19,20 respectively

I worked out like these since they are dictionaries within the files but problem with dictionary is "order" so values are not coming in right order.

At standard input, I am providing file#1.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
   d = ast.literal_eval(line)
   for k,v in d.items():
      inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(k, {})
      inner_dict['sscore !=0'] = v.get('sscore !=0')
   f = open("file#2.txt","r")
   for score in f:
      d2 = ast.literal_eval(senti)


   print k,dicts[k]['sscore !=0'],d2.keys()
   f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved:

```
dicts = {}
inner_dict = {}
```

**#Opens file in read format**

```
with open("file#1.txt","r") as f:
```

**Zip helps keeps the values as-is**

```
   for line, score in zip(sys.stdin, f):
```

**#interprets it as a dictionary**

```
      d2  = ast.literal_eval(score)
```

**#for key, value in items of dictionary**

```
      for k,v in d2.items(): 
         inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(k, {})
```

**#gets the value in value part of the dictionary since its dictionary within a dictionary**

```
         inner_dict['sscore !=0'] = v.get('sscore !=0')
```

**#prints the key of dictionary,gets value of sscore corresponding to its key, gets the first column value by splitting by space**

```
      print k,dicts[k]['sscore !=0'],re.split("\s+", line.strip())[0]
```

If anyone can improve the code, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use `zip` like this

```
with open("file#2.txt","r") as f:
    for line, score in zip(sys.stdin, f):
        ...
```

Comment: I did not understand how I would be using zip. Zip seems useful